# I have a query on auto increment on sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

I have the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTION (
    QUES_ID  INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT,
    TOPIC_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    QUESTION_DESC TEXT NOT NULL,
    CHOICE_A TEXT,
    CHOICE_B TEXT,
    CHOICE_C TEXT,
    CHOICE_D TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (QUES_ID,TOPIC_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TOPIC_ID) REFERENCES TOPIC(TOPIC_ID)
);
```

When I insert info like that...

```
INSERT INTO 
    QUESTION (TOPIC_ID,QUESTION_DESC,CHOICE_A,CHOICE_B,CHOICE_C,CHOICE_D)
VALUES 
    (1,'Blue or blue?','red?','yellow?','black?','yellow again?');
```

I get the following results, the `ques_id` doesn't get assigned!

```
QUES_ID     TOPIC_ID   QUESTION_DESC  CHOICE_A  CHOICE_B  CHOICE_C  CHOICE_D     
----------  ---------  -------------  --------- --------- --------- -------------
             1         Blue or blue?  red?      yellow?   black?    yellow again?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1):

> A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement.

So your DDL statement should look more like:

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTION (
    QUES_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    TOPIC_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    QUESTION_DESC TEXT NOT NULL,
    CHOICE_A TEXT,
    CHOICE_B TEXT,
    CHOICE_C TEXT,
    CHOICE_D TEXT,
    -- the primary key must be QUES_ID 
    -- if you want it to auto-increment
    -- so if you really want you can add 
    -- a unique constraint here
    CONSTRAINT qt UNIQUE (QUES_ID, TOPIC_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TOPIC_ID) REFERENCES TOPIC (TOPIC_ID)
);
```

Comment: This will not take away my qualified assosiation with Topic table?

Answer (score 0):

Try `QUES_ID AUTO_INCREMENT`

and really if you always want it to be there make it

```
QUES_ID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:
`QUES_ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting data like this :

```
INSERT INTO QUESTION values (1,'Blue or blue?','red?','yellow?','black?','yellow again?');
```

As you are not mentioning auto increment column in your query and also you have not mentioned **NOT NULL** for this, so it will skip entering data for that column.

Comment: Error: table QUESTION has 7 columns but 6 values were supplied
This error is what i got..